# Integrated Graphics chip and VRAM

Tags: hardware

Does anyone know if an integrated graphics chip can use VRAM from a designated graphics card?

A coworker of mine.... claims to have experienced a boast in performance in his CAD program by simply plugging a gtx 950 into his motherboard. He didn't connect his card to his monitor and still using integrated graphics chip.
maybe his claim is placebo but I wondered if it was possible.

Comment: A similar question can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/760493/is-it-possible-to-use-a-nvidia-gpu-to-render-graphics-if-the-monitor-is-connecte

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from my understanding. If hardware accelleration is enabled the rendering and calculations can be handled by the GPU. As for frames and and actual visual performance he would not see an improvment there as the actual display is not using the GPU.